# C#: loading Large dictionary in Memory and access it from multiple application

Tags: c#

for performance issue and large numbers of hits per second, I need to add about 4GB of data in Memory using dictionary and access it from multiple applications using dictionary key. this data can be updated from time to time

what is the best way to create this scenario using C#

Comment: "Best" by what criteria?  Which ways have you tried/explored thus far?

Comment: Your question is way too broad for an SO answer. The short answer, though, is use a cache product.

Comment: Consider Redis.

Comment: Use a database that is designed to handle large amount of data and allows multiple users.

Comment: my main concern is the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a *Distributed Cache* in this case like [`Redis`](https://redis.io/) since you want the data to be accessible over multiple applications and having it in-memory won't be accessible to multiple applications. Moreover, Redis do have many good C# drivers and one of which is [`StackExchange.Redis`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

Comment: so Redis won't be accessible to multiple applications?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if I would design my application like this but you can share data between applications using [Memory Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files).

Consider using alternatives like mentioned, a database.

Comment: is there an example about how to add dictionary  to a Memory Mapped Files and how to read from it by key (not all the file )

Comment: Sure, there is a ton out there. 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Inter-process-communication-e96e94e7

Comment: I think the MMF is the best solution.
the above link doesn't answer the question about How to add large dictionary to a Memory Mapped Files  and read specific values from this dictionary from another application

Comment: There are 1000 ways you can do this the wrong way, that's why I told perhaps look at database or Rahul mentioned Redis, have a look at https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/streaming-dotnet-4-5/exercise-files. just dumping code here without you understanding it is surely not going to be helping you. here is a sample https://github.com/jprichardson/MemMapCache/blob/master/MemMapCache/Program.cs

Answer (score -1):

Programs are designed to be isolated for stability and security.

A database is designed for concurrent users.

If it is single application you can use static and it is shared by all instances of the class.